# boolean value check in soundpool android

Tags: android, soundpool

Edit : this code if load soundpool sound set boolean true .

log cat load 3 sound but loaded not true .

```
boolean loaded = false;

 SoundPool sp = new SoundPool(70, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    sp.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                                   int status) {
            Log.i("OnLoadCompleteListener", "Sound " + sampleId + " loaded.");

                loaded=true;

        }
    });

    final int sol [] = new int[3];
    sol[0] = sp.load(this, R.raw.x1, 1);
    sol[1] = sp.load(this, R.raw.x2, 1);
    sol[2] = sp.load(this,R.raw.x3, 1);

    if (loaded) {
        autosynce(sol);
    }
```

never not loaded == true . 
if clear this check value , playing sound .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public boolean loaded = false;
public SoundPool sp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sp = new SoundPool(3, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    sp.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
            Log.i("OnLoadCompleteListener", "Sound " + sampleId + " loaded.");
            loaded=true;
        }
    });

    int sol = new int[3];
    sol[0] = sp.load(this, R.raw.x1, 1);
    sol[1] = sp.load(this, R.raw.x2, 1);
    sol[2] = sp.load(this,R.raw.x3, 1);

    //This 100 is the number of loops, I think it will be enough, but if
    //you want to set an infinite loop, you should better use MediaPlayer
    //then, but that will prevent you from playing many sounds together.
    sp.play(sol, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 100, 1.0f);

    if (loaded) {
        //I am not sure what's that method. It's yours...
        autosynce(sol);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Eli If you have found this answer useful, please don't forget to vote it up as well. :)

Comment: this not work :( . this boolean not get true . and this code 3 time repeat sol[0] = sp.load(this, R.raw.x1, 1);
    sol[1] = sp.load(this, R.raw.x2, 1);
    sol[2] = sp.load(this,R.raw.x3, 1);

Comment: @Eli What is autosynce in your code? Is it a method you created? Please post this method if it is.

Comment: Also what do you want to do exactly? Do you want it to function as a playlist. Play one sound after another?

Comment: no this app play 3 sound on 1 time and sync . and i can with 3 button change volume and best way for create loop music . i tested 3 sound and want play more loops .

Comment: @Eli I think the reason why it wasn't loaded because you didn't call sp.play() method. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Yes i Use Media Player , for sync loop is very bad but best way .

Comment: If that solution worked for you, please don't forget to vote my answer up. Thanks. :)